# Converting Non-GUI application to GUI application (Python/Tkinker)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a non-GUI guessing game where the end user will "roll a dice" and then is asked to guess a number. The result of the 'dice roll" determines how may tries the end user gets to guess the number. Results of the game play is saved in a notepad.txt file and the notepad file is opened after gameplay.

**This code works 100%  (NON GUI - SHELL/OUTPUT ONLY GAME)**

```
import random
import time
import sys
import os

print("Welcome to the guessing game")
time.sleep(1)
userName = input("please input your name ")
time.sleep(1)
print("hi", (userName), "let me tell you how to play")
time.sleep(1)
print("the aim of the game is to guess the number the computer is thinking about")
time.sleep(1)
print("the computer roles the dice, and the result is the your number of attempts")
time.sleep(1)
print("on every attempt, the computer will guess a new number")
time.sleep(1)
print("if you guess the number, you win")
time.sleep(1)
print("lets begin")
time.sleep(2)
print("rolling the dice..")
time.sleep(3)
randNum2 = random.randrange(1, 6)
print(randNum2)
tries = 0
correct = 0

count = randNum2
while not count == 0:
    input1 = int(input("guess a number 1,100 "))
    randNum1 = random.randrange(1, 100)
    if (input1 == randNum1):
        print("correct")
        correct += 1
        break
    else:
        print("incorrect")
        if input1 > randNum1:
            print("You guessed to high")
        else:
            print("you guessed to low")

        tries += 1
        print(randNum1)
        print(count - 1)
        count -= 1
print("computer", (tries), (userName), (correct))
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
d2 = now.strftime("%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")
orig_stdot = sys.stdout
f = open('statistics.txt', 'a')
sys.stdout = f
print("the computer won", (tries), "times", (userName), "won", (correct), "times ", d2)
f.close()
os.system("statistics.txt")

# statistics = input("whould you like to view the statistics?: ")
# if statistics == "yes":
# os.system("statistics.txt")
```

I have already passed this subject in my coding class. However as I wish to gain a better understanding of coding so i am attempting to convert this non-gui game to gui (as a personal project). However, I am not finding it as simple.

**this is the code of the GUI VERSION of the game;**

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
import time
import sys
import datetime
import os

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Shanes Number Guessing Game")
window.geometry("600x500")

# GUI Image
#logo = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\Python-Tkinter pics\\numberguess.png")
#photo1 = tk.Label(image=logo)
#photo1.image = logo
#photo1.pack()

# score
tries = 0
wins = 0

# user enters their username
userNameLabel = tk.Label(window, text="please enter your name below")
userNameEntry = tk.Entry(window)
userNameLabel.pack()
userNameEntry.pack()

# User enters their guess in a entry box
enterGuessLabel = tk.Label(window, text="enter guess below")
enterGuessLabel.pack()
enterGuess = tk.Entry(window, text=0)
guess = enterGuess
enterGuess.pack()

diceResult = random.randrange(1, 6)


# Throw dice
def throwDice():
    global diceResult
    global tries

    print(diceResult)
    tries += diceResult


def takeGuess():
    global wins
    global losses
    global tries
    global diceResult
    global rannum
    count = diceResult
    while not count == 0:
        print(rannum)
        if (guess == rannum):
            print("correct")
            wins += 1
            print(wins)
            break

        else:
            print("incorrect")
            print("the number was:", (rannum))

            tries += 1
            count -= 1

    # GUI Buttons


diceButton = tk.Button(window, text="roll dice", command=throwDice)
diceButton.pack()

guessButton = tk.Button(window, text="take guess", command=takeGuess)  # button will need a comand
inputGuess = guessButton
guessButton.pack()

rannum = random.randrange(1, 100)

# Timestamp
timestamp = time.strftime("%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")
print(timestamp)


# open file
def file():
    os.system("statistics.txt")  # 'statistics.txt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,


fileButton = tk.Button(window, text="open file", command=file)
fileButton.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

**This is the output of the GUI Version of the number guessing game.**

User selects "guessButton" Tk.Button

```
"C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" "D:/Number Guess Game (GUI).py"
August 10, 2020 12:32:11
88
incorrect
the number was: 88
88
incorrect
the number was: 88
88
incorrect
the number was: 88
```

User selects "diceButton" tk.Button

```
3
```

As you can see, "guessButton" runs the def function "throwDice", this function is not working and prints "incorrect (three times in a row) on every button click, even if the user guesses the number correctly, the output will always print "incorrect" three times in one row.

(the "diceButton" that runs the command "throwDice" is working as expected and displays a random.randrange)

**This is the output of the NON-GUI VERSION, I wish for the GUI version to match this output:**

```
"C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" "D:/NUmber Guess Game - ITCPRG301.py"
Welcome to the guessing game
please input your name Shane
hi Shane let me tell you how to play
the aim of the game is to guess the number the computer is thinking about
the computer roles the dice, and the result is the your number of attempts
on every attempt, the computer will guess a new number
if you guess the number, you win
lets begin
rolling the dice..
2
guess a number 1,100 90
incorrect
You guessed to high
27
1
guess a number 1,100 27
incorrect
you guessed to low
58
0
computer 2 Shane 0
```

If i can get past this road bump I should be able to program the application to display the results of the game within the GUI instead of the shell.

Any advise will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below as a base. I rewrote your entire thing with a class structure and proper PEP8. All the problems you had are solved. Learn from this and build on top of it to finish your game.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random, time

class App(tk.Tk):
    #width, height and title are constants of your app so, write them as such
    WIDTH  = 600
    HEIGHT = 500
    TITLE  = "Shane's Number Guessing Game"
    
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
        #init vars
        self.tries  = 0
        self.wins   = 0
        self.losses = 0
        self.roll   = 0
        self.rand   = 0
        
        tk.Label(self, text="please enter your name below").grid(column=0)
        self.name = tk.Entry(self)
        self.name.grid(column=0)
        
        tk.Label(self, text="enter guess below").grid(column=0)
        self.guess = tk.Entry(self, text='0')
        self.guess.grid(column=0)
        
        self.roll_btn = tk.Button(self, text="roll dice", command=self.roll_dice)
        self.roll_btn.grid(column=0)
        
        self.guess_btn = tk.Button(self, state='disabled', text="take guess", command=self.make_a_guess)
        self.guess_btn.grid(column=0)
        
        tk.Button(self, text="save stats", command=self.stats).grid(column=0)
        
        self.rand = random.randrange(1, 100)

    def reset(self):
        self.rand = random.randrange(1, 100)
        self.roll_btn['state']  = 'normal'
        self.guess_btn['state'] = 'disabled'
        
    def roll_dice(self):
        self.roll = random.randrange(1, 6)
        self.roll_btn['state']  = 'disabled'
        self.guess_btn['state'] = 'normal'
        
    def make_a_guess(self):
        if self.roll > 0:
            self.tries += 1
            self.roll  -= 1  
            print(self.rand)
            if int(self.guess.get()) == self.rand:
                self.wins += 1
                print(f'Correct! You have {self.wins} wins')
                self.reset()
            elif self.roll < 1:
                self.losses += 1
                print(f'Incorrect. The number was {self.rand}. You have {self.losses} losses')
                self.reset()
                
    def stats(self):
        timestamp = time.strftime("%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")
        msg = f'{timestamp}: {self.wins} wins and {self.losses} losses with {self.tries} tries\n'
        with open('statistics.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(msg)


#use proper PEP8 to initialize your program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.geometry(f'{App.WIDTH}x{App.HEIGHT}')
    app.title(App.TITLE)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, your code looks more simplified and cleaner then mine.

Comment: new here, didn't know that you could only accept one answer in a question. Still studying your code. I like how you grayed out the "take guess button" till after the user rolls the dice.  I am reading up more on (self) and PEP8, its quite interesting. Thanks again.

Comment: :D. It's OK. Do you have questions? I can make my answer more informative. I purposely left it a little vague to sort of challenge your understanding. I don't mind explaining it, though.

Comment: I'm traveling along nicely with your base code, I'm just altering it to include labels in the GUI and also to save the results to a notepad, but I am enjoying the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Input via a `Entry` widget is stored as a **string**. Try to explicitly typecast `enterGuess` using `int()` before comparing it to `randNum1`.

```py
userGuessed = int(enterGuess.get())
...

if userGuess == randNum1:
    print('correct')
    ...
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: I received an error: userGuess = int(enterGuess.get())  #ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: I have been able to get the program working (with assistance from my teacher) by simply moving the  "userGuess = int(enterGuess.get())" within the def "takeguess"function.  Thanks for the assist.